# Fill between four parametric paths that together are continuous

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, fill

I have a shape made up of four paths, and I'd like to fill the inside. The four paths are given in parametric form, and each consecutive pair has exactly one point common, so I'd hope this is a well-defined problem. Note that I am using `tikz-3dplot` in my MWE, because the eventual solution will need to work in a `tikz-3dplot` environment; if I were not in 3D, I could probably draw a bunch of lines with `to` and control points to make the shape...

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  
\tdplotsetmaincoords{130}{-45}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{270}{90}{90}

\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \draw %[fill=red]
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({(8 * \t) - 4} ,3,{0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({(8 * \t) - 4} ,-3,{0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] (-4, {(6 * \t) - 3},{0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] (4, {(6 * \t) - 3},{0.3*sin(\t*180)});
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Without the `[fill=red]` part, this renders the correct shape I want:

[image]

However, if I try to fill it (by uncommenting `[fill=red]`), the result is not at all the inside of the shape filled:

[image]

In fact, now that I've pasted the picture here, I am noticing that it is somewhat related to the intended shape --- if I connected the four corners with straight edges and filled *that* parallelogram, I would only need to subtract and union the right pieces of what I *do* get filled with the above code, to arrive at my intended picture.

So, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{130}{-45}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{270}{90}{90}

\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \draw [fill=red]
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] (-4, {(6 * \t) - 3},{0.3*sin(\t*180)}) --
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({(8 *\t) - 4},3,   {0.3*sin(\t*180)}) --
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] (4,{-(6 * \t) + 3}, {0.3*sin(\t*180)}) --
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({-(8 *\t) + 4},-3, {0.3*sin(\t*180)}) 
    ;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From comparison with your code you can see, that is changes order of drawing `plot`s so, that the next `plot` start where previous end and between these pairs is added `--` (which connect those two plots).

**Edit:**
With further permutation of `plot`s order and their parameters now each `plot` has its beginning where previous has its end.

[image]

**Edit (2):**
Version with shorter code:

```
...

\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \draw [fill=red, variable=\t,domain=0:1]
    plot (-4, {(6 * \t) - 3},{0.3*sin(\t*180)}) --
    plot ({(8 *\t) - 4},3,   {0.3*sin(\t*180)}) --
    plot (4,{-(6 * \t) + 3}, {0.3*sin(\t*180)}) --
    plot ({-(8 *\t) + 4},-3, {0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    ;
\end{scope}
...
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Oh, right, so I did have them in the right order while I was banging my head against this, but I didn't realize that the endpoints don't match up due to the parameters going the wrong way. Is that what the `--` fixes?

Comment: If I zoom in on this, I can see a southwest-northeast diagonal artefact.

Comment: @Cactus, yes, it is there since fill is composed from two parts :-). However, this artefact are in normal circumstances not visible. However, with further permutation of `pltot`s I succeed to draw all `plot`s in correct order and eliminate observed artifact. See edited answer.

Comment: @Cactus `--` connects the different plots into one path. `\fill` needs closed path(s). Whenever a path is not closed with `-- cycle`, fill will close it automatically. (but I would say that it is good practice to manually close it with `-- cycle`.). Completely without `--`, there are four paths and `\fill` will close and fill each path individually.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a faint idea why, but the following works:

```
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
  \fill[fill=red, even odd rule]
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({(8 * \t) - 4} ,3,{0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] ({(8 * \t) - 4} ,-3,{0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] (-4, {(6 * \t) - 3},{0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0:1] (4, {(6 * \t) - 3},{0.3*sin(\t*180)})
    (-4,-3,0) -- ++ (8,0,0) -- ++ (0,6,0) -- ++ (-8,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
```

If the outline should also be drawn, that requires a second `\draw` with just the curved parts.